# "where" clause with only the month

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

What I want to do is to get all the days-off in my db for a given month.

I tried multiple solutions and none of them work. I ended by doing black magic with doctrine (kinda).

Here's my last attempt :

```
public function getNbCongesByMonth($month){
    $listOfEntities = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select('count(e) as nb, SUBSTRING(e.cngDateDebut, 6, 2) as day')
        ->where('day = :month')
        ->setParameter('month', $month)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $listOfEntities;
}
```

The request is supposed to return the amount of "Conges" in the database for a precise month.

With this request I got this error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT count(c0_.CNG_ID) AS sclr0, SUBSTRING(c0_.CNG_DATE_DEBUT FROM 6 FOR 2) AS sclr1 FROM Conges c0_ WHERE sclr1 = ?' with params ["5"]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr1' in 'where clause'
```

I have no ideas how to do that anymore so if someone has a solution that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain why the downvote ? I'm new here, what did I do wrong ?

Comment: I am guessing that cngDateDebut is a DateTime therefore you can compare this only with another DateTime object and not with a string, this will never work

Comment: Such query is not possible, you can't use column alias (`day` in your case) in where clause, never. It's because in any SQL database engine where clause is processed BEFORE select clause. I suggest opening new questiton, where you put your db model and put example what data you want to get and maybe someone can write you a query.

Comment: Do you want only one month from a given year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `datetime` type for the `cngDateDebut` property, you can use a `like()` condition based on the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format used by MySQL:

```
public function getNbCongesByMonth($month){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

    $listOfEntities = $qb
        ->select('count(e) as nb')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->like('e.cngDateDebut',
                $qb->expr()->literal('%-'.$month.'-%')
            )
        )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $listOfEntities;
}
```

And if you want to count only days-off for a given month from a given year:

```
public function getNbCongesByMonth($year, $month){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

    $listOfEntities = $qb
        ->select('count(e) as nb')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->like('e.cngDateDebut',
                $qb->expr()->literal($year.'-'.$month.'-%')
            )
        )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $listOfEntities;
}
```

`%` is a keyword that matches anything, so with `$month = 04`,  `'%-'.$month.'-%'` the pattern will be `'%-04-%'` and this pattern will match `2016-04-…'`, `2015-04-…'`, etc.

Comment: That's perfectly what I wanted. Now I just have to make some adjustments to fit my projects but I would have never found how to do that without you. Thanks